# How to determine if a hardware is available in Linux

Tags: linux

let's say I have as Linux computer, I do not have idea if I have a wifi extension on it. The only thing I can do is to run "modeprobe wl18_xx && modprobe wlcore_spi" then wait for several minutes watching the stdout.

Is there any other smarter way?

Comment: Any reason you can't configure your Linux computer to properly load the modules at boot, or react on hardware events when you connect a wifi extension to it? Then you can just check for existing wifi interfaces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lshw` is a program that lists details of all your available hardware. You can run it simply, and pipe the output into a pager such as `less` in order to browse and search the entire output, or if you already know what sections you are interested in, you can selectively output a 'class', in your case `lshw -class network`, which will show you details of any existing network hardware, including that of any wifi adapter(s).